# line wont display on top of background color(css problem)

Tags: css

Setting line won't appear on top of the background color,what seems to be the problem?Thank you.I have this code

```
<div class="setting-wrapper">
  <div class="setting-line"></div

   </div>
```

css

```
 .setting-wrapper{
  background-color:#E2E9E9;
  position: absolute;
  left:450px;
  top:20px; 
  border:1px solid #dedede; 
  display:block;
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius:5px;
   }
  .setting-line{
margin-top:5px; 
margin-bottom:5px;
width:500px;
   border-top:solid #e6e6e6 1px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<div class="setting-line"></div` isn't a copy/paste typo, then theres a missing bracket at the end of the closing `DIV`.

But maybe it's only hard to see a difference between `#E2E9E9` and `#e6e6e6` (depending on the systems color-depth and/or screen capabilities).

Comment: @feela Thank you ,it couldn't tell the difference between color